# Notation in Meade's paper "ODE models for the parachute problem"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

This refers to [ODE models for the parachute problem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144596316248) by Douglas B. Meade. On page four the author says:

> When $k$ is piecewise constant, the snatch force has a jump discontinuity at the instant of deployment:
>   $$[j(t_d)]:=j(t_d^+)-j(t_d^-)=-\frac{[k(t_d)a(t_d)]}{m}$$

I have two questions. What is the mathematical meaning of the brackets?

What is the mathematical meaning of the colon equals (i.e. :=)?

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $:=$ indicates that the left hand side is being *defined* to be equal to the right-hand side. The author has just made the definition that square brackets around something like $f(x)$ mean the jump of $f$ at $x$, that is $[f(x)]=f(x^+)-f(x^-)$.

And then this definition is immediately used: the expression $[k(t_d)a(t_d)]$ appearing on the right should be understood as
$$k(t_d^+)a(t_d^+)-k(t_d^-)a(t_d^-)$$